# Is a pointer an enumerable file?

Tags: pointers, types, enums, enumerable

Yesterday i was reading old exams questions and one caught me and my friends up:
Is a pointer an enumerable type? An enunerable type would mean that a value has a predecessor and a successor (like, for example, int).
Some of us say yes and some other no, with good reasons too.
Please give us advice.

Comment: This question is too abstract to answer in its current form. For theory type questions, see [the CS site](http://cs.stackexchange.com). On Stack Overflow questions should pertain to concrete code in some particular language so the technical aspects of your query can be addressed. C++ and Java and Rust all have different ideas about these things.

Comment: You cannot really ask such questions without defining your terms first. Types, pointers and enumerations in different languages all behave differently. There is no universally agreed standard set of properties these things must have. Your curricullum may include some definitions but we have no idea what they are.